# change small letter to capital letter in a column in table

Tags: text-processing

I have data was collected in the following format:

```
CREDITS,EXPDATE,USER,GROUPS
99,01 jun 2018,sylvain,team:::admin
52,01    dec   2018,sonia,team
52,01    dec   2018,sonia,team
25,01    jan   2019,sonia,team
10,01 jan 2019,sylvain,team:::admin
8,12    jun   2018,öle,team:support
```

I want to capitalize the first letter of column "user" in a way that all names begin with capital letter instead of small letter. how can I do that?

Also, how can I revise the table by removing the extra `:` and `,` then adjust the length of the columns to make it neat?

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can do it for you :

```
awk '{ $3 = toupper(substr($3,1,1)) substr($3,2) } $3' FS=, OFS=, file
CREDITS,EXPDATE,USER,GROUPS
99,01 jun 2018,Sylvain,team:::admin
52,01    dec   2018,Sonia,team
52,01    dec   2018,Sonia,team
25,01    jan   2019,Sonia,team
10,01 jan 2019,Sylvain,team:::admin
8,12    jun   2018,Öle,team:support
```

The function `substr` has the following format `substr(s, a, b)`, it returns b number of chars from string s, starting at position a. The parameter b is optional. 
It can split a string of characters at a given length. Here, it capitalize only the first character of the third field, `substr` function takes the initial string, the first based index of the first character to extract, and the number of characters to extract. If that last argument is missing, `substr` takes all the remaining characters of the string.

Having said that, `substr($3,1,1)` will evaluate to the first character of $3, and `substr($3,2)` to the remaining ones.

In order to remove extra unnecessary chars you can pipe the output to `sed`  then to `column` to adjust the length of the columns

```
awk '{ $3 = toupper(substr($3,1,1)) substr($3,2) } $3' FS=, OFS=, file | sed -e 's/,/\t/g' -e 's/:/ /g' | awk '{print $1, $2","$3","$4"  "$5" " $6" " $7" "$8}' | column -t
CREDITS  EXPDATE,USER,GROUPS
99       01,jun,2018          Sylvain  team  admin
52       01,dec,2018          Sonia    team
52       01,dec,2018          Sonia    team
25       01,jan,2019          Sonia    team
10       01,jan,2019          Sylvain  team  admin
8        12,jun,2018          Öle      team  support
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How can organize this table. I mean remove the extra `:` and adjust the length between the columns?

Comment: @Koran you are welcome, would you please update the question by including this additional question. Please include the expected output s well! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @goro just one last question. the words `teamadmin` must be `team admin`

Comment: @Koran please see the edits.

Comment: I prefer use only one awk with column : awk '{ $3 = toupper(substr($3,1,1)) substr($3,2);gsub(/  *|::*/," ") } 1' FS=, OFS=, infile | column -ts ',' .Yours fails with a user like anne marie :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that many pipes as in Goro's proposal are needed; it should be doable in a single `awk` script, followed by `column` if need be only:

```
awk '
    {gsub (/[   ]+/, "/", $2)
     $3 = toupper(substr($3,1,1)) substr($3,2)
     gsub (/,/, "\t")
     gsub (/:+/, " ")
    }
1

' FS=, OFS=, file
CREDITS EXPDATE USER    GROUPS
99      01/jun/2018 Sylvain team admin
52      01/dec/2018 Sonia   team
52      01/dec/2018 Sonia   team
25      01/jan/2019 Sonia   team
10      01/jan/2019 Sylvain team admin
8       12/jun/2018 öle team support
```